# PHP numeric for each with substr_count

Tags: php

Okay let me simplify..

I have a list of ids in a variable `$paramsId = 10,38,8,4,36,`..
I now need to separate these numbers into separate variables so i used `list($slide1, $slide2, $slide3, $slide4, $slide5) = explode(",", $params->get('id'));`
then i placed it in a array:

```
$a = array(
    "one" => $slide1,
    "two" => $slide2,
    "three" => $slide3,
    "four" => $slide4,
    "five" => $slide5
);
```

and then it gets put into a foreach statement:

```
foreach ($a as $k => $val) {
    $args = $val;
    $item[] = ModArticleSlider::getArticles($args);
}
```

all i am trying to achieve is that foreach number in $paramsId separate the values with a "," and then place each seperated value into variables named "$slider1, $slider2(and so forth)" then place those variables in an array.

Any Help Greatly Appreciated.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve ?

Comment: are you trying to increase `$paramsId` by one?

Comment: I have updated the question hopefully its less confusing.. thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just use

```
$a = explode(",", $params->get('id'));
```

then try a print_r($a) and check if your values are in the array.